# Illustrator - object placements slightly off

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I'm currently lerning Illustrator and I started building some Lego bricks for learning purposes. Building them worked, but when I try to stack them over each other, they just won't align proberly. Take a look at these screenshots:

[image: This is how it looks when I drag and hold my grouped Lego object]

This is how it looks when I drag and hold my grouped Lego object to where I want it. As you can see, the paths align perfectly.

[image: But if I let go, that happens]

But if I let go, that happens. The bricks aren't properly aligned, the blue brick is slightly shifted up and left.

Why does this happen? And how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the menu **View** and uncheck all "snap to [...]" options and see if it works.

**Snap to point** and **Snap to Grid** often produced those kind of Problems for me.

Also use the Align-Tools to move the objects together. Mouse-moves also sometimes work weird.

Hope this helps. Sry for bad english!

Comment: The snapping option weren't the culprit, but I could fix the alignment using the alignment tool! Thanks!